# how do i back up a mysql database on my server onto my computer?

Tags: mysql, terminal

I want to delete all the contents on my digitalocean server and start afresh. It's a ruby on rails project, want to make it java.

But I want to keep one of the databases. Is it possible to backup the database onto my computer? I would have thought it would be straight forward but I've been googling a while with no luck.

The closest I can find is mysql 'dumping' it into another part of the server like :

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_to_backup > backup_name.sql
```

And then restoring it somewhere else on the server. But I want to put it on my computer and then delete all the stuff on my server.

Comment: With `phpmyadmin`, you can dump directly to a local file from the web.  Otherwise, just use `scp` or `ftp` to recover your `backup_name.sql` from the remote server.  Create a local database and `source backup_name.sql` into it.

Comment: can't you use scp or ftp to copy backup_name.sql to your local machine?

Comment: that's the reason I'm cleaning out my server, I'm having trouble installing phpmyadmin. I can access my database with command line, see tables etc...but how can I find out where the database is actually located? Then I could try copying over ibd or frm files or whatever.

Comment: @Fabricator mysql databases don't end with .sql I'm pretty sure, it's more like .ibd, .frm, .myd...

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be to install PHPmyadmin and then dump the database into a .sql file, for importing later, Digital Ocean have a guide on their website about installing, and securing it. 
This will also make managing the database later, much easier.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Yes, read that guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-backup-mysql-databases-on-an-ubuntu-vps. It dumps the mysql file onto another part of the server. How can I back it up using command line, onto my computer? Unfortunately I'm having trouble installing phpmyadmin on my server. That's why I want to wipe my server and start again.

Comment: It should directly download it? Did you select .sql file as the output for the dump.

Comment: If that is not working are you able to FTP into the server? if so you can do a normal:

mysqldump --databases database_one database_two > two_databases.sql
the location of the dump will be either root or the current location where you ran the command.

Comment: managed to log into the mysql folder (as root, didn't have permission before that), can see all the tables like abc.frm, dfg.frm etc...might just try copying these to my computer, that's probably the bes thing. thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. glad I could help.

Comment: can't you export it all into a import query? so that you can just create a blank database then run the query to import all your data